# Generate JSONPatch for instance data based on two JSONSchema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-patch

I search a tool which permit to generate [JSONPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/) from two [JSONSchema](https://json-schema.org/). Example:

JSONSchema A:

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Where JSON object can be:

```
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 42 }
```

JSONSchema B (without age):

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    }
  }
}
```

Generated JSONPatch should be:

```
[
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/age" }
]
```

To obtain after apply patch, object:

```
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }
```

There are some tools for that ?

NB: I can find some tools like [this](https://github.com/gregsexton/json-patch-gen) or [this](https://python-json-patch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) but these generate JSONPatch from **objects** not from JSONSchemas.

Comment: JSON Schema is JSON. Why do you believe that what will work for JSON will not work for "A JSON Schema"?

Comment: Because the JSONPatch generated from these two JSONSchema will not permit patching objects matching with first JSONSchema. Current "pure JSON"  JSONPatch generated from these two JSONSchema is `[{ "op": "remove", "path": "/properties/age" }]` not `[{ "op": "remove", "path": "/age" }]`.

Comment: In which case, I think you're very unlikely to see such tooling. JSON Schema is very much more complex than just a field or not existing. Your best bet would be to make some tooling which, for simple cases, can transform the transform from two schemas.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this remark.